# AdvancePythonScheduler Pause Job

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I am working with APScheduler and would like to pause and resume job based on the request. Below is the code I have tried.

```
        from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
        from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore
        from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
        from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
        from apscheduler.schedulers.base import BaseScheduler
        
        jobstores = {
            'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
        }
        
        executors = {
            'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
            'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
        }
        job_defaults = {
            'coalesce': False,
            'max_instances': 3
        }
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, 
        job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
    
           def testTrigger():
             print("APScheduler...")

    //Adding Job
    scheduler.add_job(testTrigger,'interval',seconds=5,id='schedule_1')
    
    //Pausing Job
    BaseScheduler.pause_job(job_id='schedule_1')
```

I am facing the following error `pause_job() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you're using the wrong variable. it would be `scheduler.pause_job`. you're trying to call the function from the wrong scheduler, not to mention you are trying to call it as if it was a `staticmethod`, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
scheduler.pause_job(job_id='schedule_1')
```

Don't use BaseScheduler.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
scheduler.get_job('schedule_1').pause()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, but I use a variable to manage the main job.

```python
schedule_1 = scheduler.add_job(testTrigger, 'interval', seconds=5)
```

Then the following to pause or stop...

```python
def testTrigger():
  schedule_1.pause()
  do_something_maybe_longer_than_the_interval()
  schedule_1.resume()
```